# Streaming data from Flume 1.4 Serializer to Hbase 0.96

Tags: hbase, flume

I am trying to Load streaming data to Hbase 0.96 using Flume 1.4 and Zookepper 3.4.5

it gives me following error  when starting flume :

```
ERROR [lifecycleSupervisor-1-1] (org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink.start:138)  - Could not load table, MyHbaseTable from HBase
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:150)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink$1.run(HBaseSink.java:127)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink$1.run(HBaseSink.java:124)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink.runPrivileged(HBaseSink.java:327)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink.start(HBaseSink.java:124)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.start(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:46)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner.start(SinkRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.createConnection(HConnectionManager.java:387)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$Result overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.<clinit>(ProtobufUtil.java:172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ClusterId.parseFrom(ClusterId.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKClusterId.readClusterIdZNode(ZKClusterId.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(HConnectionManager.java:801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:633)
    ... 24 more
```

Anyone knows why it is giving such error..Although i have respective jars loaded.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$Result overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;`

Something is screwy in your classpath. I imagine you've got an incorrect version of the Google protobuffers in there.

This error message is because the JVM attempted to load `ClientProto` and went to verify that it met all the requirements. It already had something from Google protobuf loaded and so the verification failed.

Answer (score 0):

add protobuf jar dependency in maven

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```